# Authenticate UBER API through AngularJS 6 & Node

Tags: node.js, angular, uber-api

I am working on an application, in this application we consume UBER API. I am using NODE as backend and AngularJS 6 as frontend.

**Workflow**
[image]

In NODE part I have access authentication and other UBER API. i have tested through JQuery. It's working perfectly. But when I am trying to access with AngularJS 6. I am getting following error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:11697:51) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:41155:33) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36) at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47) at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17)
text: "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Flogin&scope=profile%20history%20places%20request&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:1455/api/login"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:1455/api/login"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Here is my code
NODE

```
app.get('/api/login', function(request, response) {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');    
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    var authURL=uber.getAuthorizeUrl(config.uber.scopes);
    response.redirect(authURL);
});
```

AngularJS 6

**data.service.ts**

```
 UberAuthenticate(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:1455/api/login');      
  }
```

**login.components.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.UberAuthenticate().subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log('response is ', response)
    },(error) => {
      console.log('error is ', error)
  })
  }
}
```

My Node application in running on **PORT:1455**, AngularJS **PORT:4200** and callback url `http://localhost:1455/api/callback`.
I also set some configuration in **proxy.config.json**

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:1455",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": false,
      "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
  }
```

I haven't experience on NODE and AngularJS 6. I don't know where I am doing wrong?

Comment: AngularJS or Angular?

Comment: When you say it works from jQuery, you mean that you made the full code in jQuery, or it works with that node code and jQuery? If is the 2nd answer, it could be ```{ withCredentials: true }```  option, if is the first... hmm... i would do the login with passportjs

Answer (score 0):

Since the authorize endpoint is returning a plain text link, you need to specify it to angular in your service like this:

```
UberAuthenticate(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:1455/api/login', { responseType: 'text' });      
}
```

And in the NodeJS part, you will have to return the authorization url, the redirection has to be made in the frontend side.